# What sort of URL structure should be used to display AMP HTML vs vanilla HTML

Tags: seo, url, duplicate-content, amp

There's an existing WordPress plugin that creates AMP formats automatically by adding `/amp` onto the end of any posts URL.

I'm worried about duplicating my content at multiple URLs and wondering if adding some parameter like `?v=amp` would be better?

Also, if a parameter is used to render the page via AMP, how do we let Google know about these pages? Can we submit a separate AMP sitemap?

Comment: What about `rel="canonical"`?

Comment: With [Proper canonical implementation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery) you shouldn't have any duplicate content problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link to your AMP version use:

`<link rel="amphtml" href="/{/path/to/amp.html}">`

For the backlink from AMP version to the desktop version use:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com">`